# Special Characters Causing MySQL Failures

Tags: php, html, mysql, character-encoding

For my current project, I'd like to make a browser for a dictionary database I have in MySQL. These words contain special characters, and I'm using UTF-8 encoding. So far, I've made a functioning "search" that looks up the user's input and outputs the relevant information.

Here's where I run into an issue. If the user inputs all normal characters, the code works properly. However, if they put in something with any special characters, the query always returns null.

Here's the relevant code:

HTML Page:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="test.php" method="get">
            Search dictionary: <input type="text" name="search">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP Script (Excerpt):

```
<?php
    $q=$_GET['search'];
    $id = "";
    if (strlen($q) > 0) {
        // connects to DB
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=***', '***', '***');
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");

        $query="SELECT DISTINCT e.lexeme_id, l.posc
        FROM entry e
        INNER JOIN lexeme l 
        USING (lexeme_id)
        WHERE e.lemma = '".$q."'";

        $stmt=$db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();

        foreach ($stmt as $row) {
            $id = $row['lexeme_id'];
            $posc = $row['posc'];
            //output results here
            echo "<h1>".$q."</h1><br/>";
            echo "<h2>".$posc."</h2><br/>";
        }
    }
?>
```

If I input "man" into the search box, the appropriate data is pulled up. However, if I search for "maðr" I get no results. However, if I try the same query in MySQL Workbench, I get the correct output. I've had the script print out the query it uses, and it matches what it should be.

TL;DR: The following query runs file in MySQL Workbench, but not when I call it on my HTML page through a PHP script-

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.lemma
FROM entry e
INNER JOIN lexeme l 
USING (lexeme_id)
WHERE e.lexeme_id = "maðr"
```

Any idea what might be going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Make sure all your scripts (your php scripts, your html files and and everything else) are encoded utf8.

Comment: As of right now, I'm just running what I've posted here. Have I set the encoding appropriately?

Comment: You have to check this in your files. Many code editors (p.e. notepad++) have options like "convert to utf8" or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
```

In your PHP script to make it UTF8

Comment: I've tried this, but to no avail. I think I've added UTF8 encoding at every possible juncture, but it's still misbehaving.

Comment: I have no idea why, but it seems to be working properly now. o.O